# Using advance SELECT statement for SQL QUERY

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to use sql query to show `name_id` and `name` attribute for all the people who have only grown tomato (`veg_grown`) and the result are show ascending order of name attribute.

```
CREATE TABLE people
(
    name_id# CHAR(4) PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    address VARCHAR2(80) NOT NULL,
    tel_no CHAR(11) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE area
(
    area_id# CHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY,
    name_id# REFRENCES people,
    area_location_adress VARCHAR2(80) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE area_use
(
     area_id# REFERENCES area,
     veg_grown VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL
)
```

but the `veg_grown` attribute has no relation to the `people` table but the people and `area_use` table are linked through area table so I tried using `INNER JOIN` like this which I confused my-self and didn't even work:

```
SELECT 
    name, name_id
FROM 
    people
INNER JOIN 
    area USING (name_id)

SELECT area_id
FROM area
INNER JOIN area_use USING (area_id)
WHERE veg_grown = 'tomato'
ORDER BY name ASC;
```

Surely there must be a way to select `name_id` and `name` who has only grown tomato in SQL query

I will take any help or advice :) thanks

Comment: According to the data model, an area can have only one name, is that really what you mean to do?

Comment: this table is short version where i am trying to have customer information in people table. and have information about their land in area table and which vegetable are grown in the area are in area_use table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.name, p.name_id
FROM people p
JOIN area a
  ON p.name_id = a.name_id
JOIN area_use au
  ON a.area_id = au.area_id
 AND au.veg_grown = 'tomato'
LEFT JOIN area_use au2
  ON a.area_id = au2.area_id
 AND au2.veg_grown <> 'tomato'
WHERE au2.area_id IS NULL;
```

This will use a `LEFT JOIN` to find people that *only* grow tomatoes. To find people that grow tomatoes and possibly anything else too, remove the `LEFT JOIN` part and everything below it.

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7afd1/2).

EDIT: If your field names contain `#` in the actual table, you'll need to quote the identifiers and add the `#`, I left them out in this sample.

Answer (score 1):

AFAICT you only want entries where all info is available, so there are no left/right joins.

```
SELECT p.name_id, p.name
FROM people p
JOIN area a
ON p.name_id = a.name_id
JOIN area_use au
ON a.area_id = au.area_id
WHERE au.veg_grown = 'tomato'
ORDER BY p.name ASC
```

Comment: it gives me error at line 4 "ORA-00904: "A"."name_id": invalid identifier

Comment: Works when dropped in the SQLFiddle :-). I did miss the "only" bit out though!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure of your data model, but this seems to be what you're trying to do.

```
SELECT name, people.name_id
FROM people, area, area_use
WHERE area.area_id = area_use.area_id
AND veg_grown = 'tomato'
AND area.name_id = people.name_id
ORDER BY name ASC;
```

Comment: it gives me ERROR at line 1 ORA-00918: column ambiguosly defined

Comment: I edited the query to unambiguize it. As noted, above, if you have '#' in the column names, you'll have to include those and quote the column names.